# Name Spring Bean with a Static Variable

Tags: java, spring

I was trying to name a bean like this:

```
<bean id="${EntityManager.ALGO}" class="path.AlgoManagerImpl">
        <property name="dao" ref="algoDao" />
</bean>
```

Where:

```
public interface EntityManager<T> {

    /** */
    public static final String ALGO = "algoManager654321";
```

So i could just get the bean like:

```
EntityManager<Algo> algoMngr = (EntityManager<Algo>) appContext
                    .getBean(EntityManager.ALGO);
```

but i get:

```
Offending resource: class path resource ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 7 in XML document from class path resource is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 101; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${EntityManager.ALGO}' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location
```

...

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 101; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${EntityManager.ALGO}' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.
```

How could i specify a static String to name that resource instead of copy/paste that specific name everywhere? is it even posible?

Comment: Not sure if possible, but seems like this may cause problems when doing maintenance to this code.

Comment: I'm new to spring, and that's one of the things i want to avoid, 'cos is hard to remember the name of every single bean

Comment: What's hard on remembering the name of the bean? Usually, it's the name of the interface but with camelCase that starts with lowercase.

Comment: And why are you *trying* to use the bean names instead of wiring by type?

Comment: you mean? appContext.getBean(appContext.getBeanNamesForType(AlgoManagerImpl.class)[0]);

Comment: You should't be looking up beans yourself, that is what you should be using dependency injection for. Hence either configure the wiring in XML or use `@Autowired` to get a reference to an, in this case, `EntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: Note that even if this shouldn't be needed, this would be easy if you used Java configuration instead of XML.

Comment: @M.Deinum Note that using `@Autowired` with `EntityManagerFactory` usually causes problems; `@PersistenceUnit` instead.